# Startup time of UIWebView component?

Tags: ios, performance, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

For an iOS app (written in C# / MonoTouch) I'm using a UIWebView to render some content dynamically. While this works fine, I run into one annoying issue: the first time I use the UIWebView (since the app startup), it takes a few seconds to show any content. Can this be overcome?

I do not "recycle" the instantiated UIWebView, on each screen I use a UIWebView, I create a new viewcontroller / UIWebView combination.

I've tried to instantiate a random UIWebView in my appdelegate, but that doesn't yield any effect (perhaps because it's not visible).

Thanks!

Comment: is the WebView content local or remote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you better [fire out](http://docs2.xamarin.com/ios/Videos/Details/Optimizing-CPU-Performance-in-Xamarin-apps-with-Instruments) Apple's Instruments to find out exactly where the time goes.

I *suspect* this comes, at least in part, from loading and initializing the web browser library in your application process. That would be a **one shot** price to pay, which sounds similar to your description.

*If* that's really the case then you might be able to *pre-load* the library, e.g. in a separate thread (but taking care not to call any thread sensitive code) when you start your application.

That should make the *first* use time similar to the *second* (and further) times. Since that initialization would be done on a separate thread then it should not impact too much (on multi-core devices at least) your application initialization.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using the Instruments tool I found that a JavaScript loaded in my UIWebView was causing this. Not loading the Js made the UIWebView start really fast.

On a sidenote: the problem itself is still rather strange, the loaded js (jquery.mobile, minified) is only slow when being loaded in the first html I load since the app starts. In case I load it in another random html, it loads really fast. Strange...

Comment: @RobinDiederen I'm glad it helped :-) Please take the time to upvote or accept answers (see FAQ) so this can also be useful to other people as well. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

You want to play around with these methods:

```
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView


-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Add the conditions in those methods and then you can have the ViewController do things while the webpage is loading.